# As3 - Transforming an image like leaning backward

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, transformation

I want to transform an image/bitmap as it is leaning backwards. If it is not clear what am trying to say please refer pic1 (original) pic2 (transformed)

```
pic1

  -----------
  -----------
  -----------
  -----------
  -----------


pic2
     -----
    -------
   ---------
  -----------
 -------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply as `pic2.rotationX = -30;`

Keep in mind that `pic2` will be rotated relative to registration point. If `pic2` registration point is at 0,0 and you want to rotate it through center, you could add it to a container sprite, set `pic2` coordinates to be centered at 0,0 relative to the container and then perform transformation on the container, like so:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(pic2);
pic2.x = -pic2.width * 0.5;
pic2.y = -pic2.height * 0.5;
container.rotationX = -30;
```